# Socket io remove user on discocnnet

Tags: javascript, sockets

i have maps which shows markers created by users and data is coming from backend node js here is clientside code to handle disconnect user but its not working any ideas ?

// Handle Disconnted User

```
socket.on('disconnectId', function (data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    const element = markers[i];
    if (data.disconnetId == element.id) {
      markers.setMap(null);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify index of marker which needs to be deleted

```
markers[i].setMap(null);
```

the correct code

```
socket.on('disconnectId', function (data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    const element = markers[i];
    if (data.disconnetId == element.id) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
});
```